# Tagging/Dimension Reduction/Clustering modeling problem

Tags: classification, clustering, predictive-models, dimensionality-reduction, predictor

Let's think of this as a stock selection (it's not, but just for the sake of easier understanding).

I have N stocks. I have M events. Each event is tagged with a list of tags T[1]... T[k]. there can be a LOT of tags, more than the number of events even.

I want to find a way that suggests, if I see this group of tags, then the stock will go up the next day. It doesn't have to be a classification problem (i.e. outcomes are stocks going up or not). It would give a gradient of outcome.

Events are not necessarily independent. in practice, M/N is roughly 1 for each day, though certainly one stock could have more than 1 event on a certain date, while some stocks would only have an event every few days. The total number of tags are roughly in the same order of magnitude with N/M too. How many tags per particular event vary greatly.

The key issue is that there are a lot of tags. So some dimension reduction is definitely needed.

Comment: Please provide more information: are the events independent? are the number of tags increasing with the number of stocks or are they a large finite number? what is the sample size you are dealing with? What is $M/N$?

Comment: @Sid I updated the original post.